# How to disable SoughtRules in SpamAssassin

Tags: spamassassin, amavis, amazon-linux-2

I'm running SpamAssassin 3.4 via Amavisd 2.12, installed with `yum` from EPEL on Amazon Linux 2. According to the SpamAssassin Confluence wiki ([here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/ImproveAccuracy) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/SoughtRules)), SoughtRules should be disabled, but ... I can't figure out where it's configured. How do I turn it off?

I'm pretty sure it's running, because I keep getting cron emails that say

`channel: no 'mirrors.sought.rules.yerp.org' record found, channel failed`

Googling around, that seems to be tied to SoughtRules, but the only configuration info I can find is on the [Plesk forum](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/spamassassin-sought-rules-yerp-org-channel-failed.360083/#post-890533), which indicates some configuration like

```
# SoughtRules - SPAMASSASSIN - Apache Software Foundation
CHANNELURL=sought.rules.yerp.org
KEYID=6C6191E3
```

out to be commented out. But, not only can I not find anything like that, I can't find anything that seems like it might be related to this at all, anywhere in either `/etc/mail/spamassassin` or `/etc/amavisd`.

Answer (score 0):

Check folder /etc/mail/spamassassin/channel.d/ - that's where the sought.conf resided on my system, and after renaming it to sought.conf.off, the nessage was no more.

I know the question's old, but the very same problem reappeared for me a few days ago, and I thought I'd document a possible solution.